# SSRS - Creating a calculated field (subtract one group value from its next) based on Column and Row Regions

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I am have the following SSRS Report challenge, my data is a row based daily grouped return count, i.e

```
EntryTotal      Subcategory    EntryDate     EnrtyStatus
10              GROUP 1        01/06/2016    CLOSED
15              GROUP 1        01/06/2016    OPENED
20              GROUP 2        01/06/2016    CLOSED
15              GROUP 2        01/06/2016    OPENED
10              GROUP 1        02/06/2016    CLOSED
15              GROUP 1        02/06/2016    OPENED
20              GROUP 2        02/06/2016    CLOSED
15              GROUP 2        02/06/2016    OPENED
```

I have the following report Matrix setup, and in I am really struggling to find the correct logical statement to use in the expression to create a difference calculation of CLOSED - (minus) OPEN for each Bottom grouping.

The Highlighted (yellow) figures are what I am trying to achieve based on my matrix grouping below

[image]

and this is my matrix I have that I hope you can help me with the logical expression statement.

[image]

Thanks for any help you can give.

Answer (score 0):

this will probably work

```
=sum(iif(Fields!EnrtyStatus.Value ="CLOSED",Fields!EntryTotal.Value,0)) -
sum(iif(Fields!EnrtyStatus.Value ="OPENED",Fields!EntryTotal.Value,0))
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, unfortunately it just returns zero's for each entry.